Ceph storage: erasure code used space calculation
I have an EC pool used for object storage in Ceph. The EC is 3+2 scheme, and the pool has stored 289 TiB.
As I understand, the total storage will be used after doing EC will be:
289 TiB * 5 / 3 = 481 TiB
But ceph df command tells different, the used space is 610 TiB:
POOL                     ID   PGS   STORED  OBJECTS     USED  %USED  MAX AVAIL
default.rgw.b.data       23  2048  289 TiB  690.43M  610 TiB  65.86    190 TiB

Did I understand anything wrong?
Thanks

There are a couple of possible explanations, for example it could be the overhead with a small object size. Depending on your ceph release, in older releases the default allocation size was 64k, so a single chunk with only a few KB would consume 64k. If you scale that up, it's quite significant. In newer releases they reduced the default to 4k. With RGW you might have lots of objects to be removed (garbage collection). It's difficult to be more specific without more information.

Just one example from a production cluster I have access to with the same EC profile (k=5, m=3): rgw.buckets.data 62 TiB net with 17.58M objects, result in 106 TiB used. This is quite close to the calculation 62*5/3 = 103 TB, so I'd say the overhead is not too large, although 3 TB is definitely worth mentioning, of course. I checked the average object size which is roughly 4M, that would explain why the overhead isn't too big in this case.
